# Move conversation error

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I'm trying to move a service broker conversation to another group conversation.
The code is:

```
    declare @handle uniqueidentifier;
    declare @conversationGroup uniqueidentifier;

    begin dialog conversation @handle
        from service ConsolidatorService
        to service 'ConsolidatorTargetService'
        on contract  [//Gereon/Consolidator/ConsolidatorContract] 
        with encryption = off;


    get conversation group @conversationGroup from [ConsolidatorTargetQueue];
    if(@conversationGroup is not null)
        move conversation @handle to @conversationGroup;

    send on conversation @handle message type [//Gereon/Consolidator/GeBasicChangesMessage]
    (@MessageBody);
```

But SQL Server returns me the error 
*The destination conversation group '60EEBC15-E75E-E611-80CC-00155D090304' is invalid.*

I can't understand why the group_conversation_id returned by get conversation is not valid.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to move the *initiator* handle to a group on the *target* service. Moving conversations can only succeed within the same service and queue.

Your question is a common issue with attempting to achieve grouping of conversations on the receiving end. There are two alternatives patterns to achieve what you want:

- you can move the conversation on target, after you RECEIVE the first message. This implies you have a method to distinguish first message from the subsequent ones, the conversation will not be grouped for the first message received, and is prone to deadlocks due to conversation group locking between concurrent receivers. Due to these problems, I do not recommend this pattern.
- you can *reverse* the dialog direction. Instead of beginning the conversation from `ConsolidatorService` to `ConsolidatorTargetService`, start the dialog from `ConsolidatorTargetService` to `ConsolidatorService` *and specify the desired group in the `BEGIN CONVERSATION` itself*. Then send a message from target to initiator. RECEIVE this message on the initiator and then use this initiator received handle for subsequent sends from `ConsolidatorService`. This makes sense only if you intend to send many messages. This pattern works, but is a bit tricky to implement correctly.

Now, the $1M question: *why* do you want to group the conversations on the target? There are valid uses for this, but I would like to hear your reasoning.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to create a trigger that sends messages on a queue, and on the other side a stored procedure receives them. But what I want is that messages are correlated in the same conversation_group. Is not important the order of the messages, but the conversation is important, because sp have to receive all the messages correlated with the same correlation_group_id (sp receives only 1 msg at a time). I've tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38878407/ms-sql-server-2012-service-broker-begin-conversation-error?noredirect=1#comment65142517_38878407), but no success

Comment: Ok, I've already tried to write the begin dialog  in this way "from ConsolidatorTarget to ConsolidatorTargetService", and it works. But it sound i little bit weird writing the begin dialog for an initiator in this way, because the initiator service is not the target.